# Graph of $(\lfloor(f(x))\rfloor)^2$

Tags: graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How do I plot $(\lfloor x^2 \rfloor)^2$?

I know how to plot $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ from $x^2$. However, where do I begin with in plotting $(\lfloor x^2 \rfloor)^2$ from$\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$?

Or more generally, how do I plot $(\lfloor f(x) \rfloor)^2$?

Comment: If you know how to graph $\lfloor x^2\rfloor$, then to graph $\left(\lfloor x^2\rfloor\right)^2$ just square all the $y$-values in the previous graph. For instance, if $\lfloor x^2\rfloor = 3$ then $\left(\lfloor x^2\rfloor\right)^2=9$ and so on.

Comment: But the function is discontinuous and I'm not sure what to do

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's discontinuous. The graph of $\lfloor x^2\rfloor$ consists of a bunch of [horizontal line segments](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1xvg1q1otc). To get the graph of $\left(\lfloor x^2\rfloor\right)^2$, look at the height of each horizontal line segment and then square it. See the comparison [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d9rsgqropd). The line segments that were at a height of $y=3$ in the original graph are at a height of $y=9$ in the new graph.

Comment: Oh yes!! How did I not think of that!! Thank you so much!